# How to set the maximum image size to upload image in django-ckeditor?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-ckeditor

I am using django-ckeditor for my project to upload image along with text content.
I used
**body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)** in model.
Now I want to restrict the user to upload large size images in content or larger than predefined maximum height/width. I want the uploaded images in content of particular height/weight and size like less then 1mb.

**How can I predefine maximum image height and width as well as maximum image size limit?**

**Is there any way to define it from django-ckeditor configuration?**

**Or How to resize the uploaded images from content at backend after user submitted the form?**

Here is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = {
      ('draft', 'Draft'),
      ('published', 'Published'),
    }
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                             choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                             default='draft')
```

I tried a lot to solve it but failed.Any suggetion to solve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE` in `setting.py`

```
CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (500, 500)
```

With the `pillow` backend, you can change the thumbnail size with the `CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE` setting (formerly THUMBNAIL_SIZE). Default value: `(75, 75)`

With the `pillow` backend, you can convert and compress the uploaded images to jpeg, to save disk space. Set the `CKEDITOR_FORCE_JPEG_COMPRESSION` setting to `True` (default `False`) You can change the `CKEDITOR_IMAGE_QUALITY` setting (formerly `IMAGE_QUALITY`), which is passed to `Pillow`:

> The image quality, on a scale from 1 (worst) to 95 (best). The default
> is 75. Values above 95 should be avoided; 100 disables portions of the
> JPEG compression algorithm and results in large files with hardly any
> gain in image quality.

This feature is disabled for animated images.

check official doc. https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/README.rst

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a way to resize the picture on uploading. But to be honest I didn't find nor in documentation neither by debugging.

However, I can suggest you a **work-around** to post-process all the images inside the content upon saving of Post model.

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image

def resize_image(filename):
    """
    here goes resize logic.
    For example, I've put 50% of current size if width>=900.
    Might be something more sophisticated
    """
    im = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = im.size
    if width >= 500:
        im = im.resize((int(width * 0.5), int(height * 0.5)))
        im.save(filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for token in self.body.split():
            # find all <img src="/media/.../img.jpg">
            if token.startswith('src='):
                filepath = token.split('=')[1].strip('"')   # get path of src
                filepath = filepath.replace('/media', settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  # resolve path to MEDIA_ROOT
                resize_image(filepath)  #do resize in-place

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The solution is not super nice because it resizes picture only **after** it was uploaded.

Probably the library itself should have some kind of exit-point/callback for image pre-processing when uploaded.